# How to know what causes an assertEquals method to fail in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, junit

I am missing **good failure messages** when using assertEquals() on objects or collections. When it fails, the error message prints out the expected object and the actual object using toString() method. **It does not print out exactly what causes the inequality.** Certainly when comparing two collections, the message that comes with the AssertionError is kind of useless or time consuming to figure out what is wrong.

**Here are two possible solutions that I don't want to use:**

1. It's an option to **write very specific assertions**, but that is **too time consuming.**
2. It's also an option to **use logging inside the equals methods** of your domain. If equals() returns false, it also prints out the attribute that causes the failure. I only need to look at my console and see the printed message right before the AssertionError. For collections on the other hand, the equals of the collection is used. If for example the lists are not equal because 1 specific object is  only present in one of the lists, I would also want that specific log message to appear in the console. But **I don't want to write that code myself**.

Are there frameworks that have this kind of logging when using equals?

Are there best practices to handle this problem (or to avoid it in the first place that you don't need this kind of logging)?

Comment: Your problem is you are calling equals on Collections. Even if they have identical contents, this will return false, since equals on a collection is a referential comparison. If you need to compare collections, iterate over them and compare their contents

Comment: I suggest you use the hamcrest matchers for Collections, as in `assertThat(yourCollection, contains(item1, item2, item3)))`

Comment: @Stultuske That's not true. The equals of collections is just fine. ArrayList loops over elements and checks order + calls equals on objects itself. A Set will check if all elements of 1 set are in the other, by also calling the equals eventually. It's about knowing why it returns false.

Comment: @user1096301 you're right, I had arrays in mind. Just ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @daniu It solves a very specific case, but only partially. It indeed says exactly which object causes the inequality of the collection. But suppose that object is quite complex and has a lot of attributes, the question remains which attribute causes the inequality. 

In practice, you need to debug. Or check the toString output of the two objects where the equals failed.

Also, for arrays, it does not check the order.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spock framework](http://spockframework.org) provides this kind of feature. You can use any expression as assertion and it will print exactly why it failed:

```
assert stack.size() == 2  // this is your assertEquals
```

And you get:

```
Condition not satisfied:

stack.size() == 2
|     |      |
|     1      false
[push me]
```

We have switched to Spock in place of JUnit in all our projects now because it's so convenient.

Comment: This is kind of the same message you get anyway. For a collection equal, it will say that its not equal and show the toString of the two collections? I'm looking for something that would say for example: "element at index 5 of your arraylist is not equal.". Or for equal of two objects: "the objects are not equal because property X has value Y and should have been value Z"

Comment: Actually you see a lot more. You see the content of the collection you see the values that are compared and you see why they are not equal. For strings Spock even shows you a diff so you can clearly see where they differ. It may not be 100% of what you want but it's a huge improvement over JUnit's output. Why not give it a spin and see if you can make it work for you?